# How to write a generic TypeScript function to group the elements of an array by any of its fields?

Tags: typescript, function, generics

Suppose I have the following array:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    age: number;
}

const people: Person[] = [
    {name: 'John',      surname: 'Smith',  age: 41},
    {name: 'Catherine', surname: 'Smith',  age: 36},
    {name: 'Paul',      surname: 'Jones',  age: 22},
    {name: 'Albert',    surname: 'Plant',  age: 22},
];
```

I need a function to return a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) grouped by any of its fields. For example, if I group by `surname`, the resulting Map will have the type `Map<string, Person[]>` with the following contents:

```
'Smith' -> [
    {name: 'John', surname: 'Smith', age: 41},
    {name: 'Catherine', surname: 'Smith', age: 36},
]
'Jones' -> [
    {name: 'Paul', surname: 'Jones', age: 22},
]
'Plant' -> [
    {name: 'Albert', surname: 'Plant', age: 22},
]
```

Similarly, if I group by `age`, this is the resulting Map will have the type `Map<number, Person[]>` with the following contents:

```
41 -> [
    {name: 'John', surname: 'Smith', age: 41},
]
36 -> [
    {name: 'Catherine', surname: 'Smith', age: 36},
]
22 -> [
    {name: 'Paul', surname: 'Jones', age: 22},
    {name: 'Albert', surname: 'Plant', age: 22},
]
```

How to write such a generic function in TypeScript, taking full advantage of its type system?

Comment: Types + implementation: https://tsplay.dev/N5Aa0N

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/ND8a6N) meet your needs? If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (edit: sniped by @pink; I'll defer to them for right of first refusal on writing an answer)

Comment: @pink Works like a charm, dude. Make it an answer, so I can award you it.